# How to include validations for key as well as value in a json schema

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I need to add validations for a property as well as a value in json schema.

I tried to use the below schema but none of the validations work :

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "minProperties": 1,
    "properties": {
        "add": {
            "type": "object",
            "patternProperties": {
                "^VOF979[0-9]{11}-NDG[0-9]{2}$": {
                    "description": "Some description",
                    "type": "string",
                    "maxLength": 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I used below json data and all the validations passes although the key and value both are wrong :

```
{
    "add": {"VOF98999990005235-NDG01": "121"}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Schema is constraints based.

`patternProperties` applies its value schema to the instance location based on the key match (in this case, regex match).

It does not prohibit additional keys in the object.

If you want to prevent additional keys, you need to specify so.

To do this, you need `"additionalProperties": false`.

Comment: Even after doing so, the schema still doesn't validate the data. I guess using 'patternProperties' inside 'properties' attribute doesn't work.

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://jsonschema.dev/s/aJRBK - What issue are you seeing?

Comment: Sorry!! It is working for me. Checked it again. Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

Do not allow additional properties to keep strict validation

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "add": {
      "type": "object",
      "patternProperties": {
                "^VOF979[0-9]{11}-NDG[0-9]{2}$": {
                    "description": "Some description",
                    "type": "string",
                    "maxLength": 2
                }
            },
      "additionalProperties": false // This One
    }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "minProperties": 1
}
```

[Reference to Docs](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#pattern-properties) Have a look at this

Comment: This schema still doesn't validate the data. I guess using 'patternProperties' inside 'properties' attribute doesn't work. Is there any other workaround ?